# Angular Schematics, how to use own schematic

Tags: angular-schematics

I can't find how to use a newly created schematics.

Here is my structure :

```html
|- tools/
  |- schematics
   |- my-first-schematic
   |- my-second-schematic
```

I want to use `my-first-schematic` within `my-second-schematic`.
I know about `externalSchematic()` but it's useful when we want to call schematif from another collection. I just want to use my own schematic.

Thanks!

Comment: from some reason, my answers are being deleted!! 
take a look at this blog it pretty much covers it
I have published a blog that explains how to create and use your own schematics:

https://medium.com/@ItayOded/automate-your-teams-boilerplates-by-building-your-own-schematics-640949001d46?source=friends_link&sk=4b90f9ecc092b598e75c5bbbd6e473a1